# Subcribe gets more records than server publishes

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to publish all admin users from server

on server something like this:

```
Meteor.publish("users_with_roles", function (options, role) {
    //{fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}}
    Counts.publish(this, 'numberOfUsers', Meteor.users.find({$and:[
            {'roles.tripro': {$exists: true}},
            {'roles.tripro': role}
        ]}),
        { noReady: true });

    return Meteor.users.find({
            $and:[
                    {'roles.tripro': {$exists: true}},
                    {'roles.tripro': role}
                 ]
        }, options);
});
```

Then on client side, I am trying to subscribe this:

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
        $meteor.subscribe('users_with_roles', {
            limit: parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
            skip: (parseInt($scope.getReactively('page')) - 1) * parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
            sort: $scope.getReactively('sort'),
            fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}
         },'admin').then(function() {
                $scope.usersCount = $meteor.object(Counts ,'numberOfUsers', false);
                console.log('user counter:' + $scope.usersCount.count);
                $scope.users.forEach( function (user) {
                    //    user.onClicked = function () {
                    //        //$state.go('userProfile', {userId: user._id});
                    //    };
                    console.log(user._id);
                });
            },
            function(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    });


    $scope.users =  $meteor.collection(function() {
        console.log('looking for role: ' + role);
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {
            //sort : $scope.getReactively('sort')
        });
    });
```

However, from the logging, it appears that the client side received all users , but from the logging on server side, it does give correct result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like you've done a publish/subscribe to get a subset of the users collection and you've called it 'users_with_roles'. But then in the function at the bottom you haven't used it, you've gone directly to the entire collection by using Meteor.users, which the core makes available in meteor clients.

Comment: Just to make sure, you don't have autopublish, right? BTW, you should not trust the user input in the publication.

Comment: no, I don't have autopublish. removed at the beginning and also meteor list to double check

Comment: I would try to inspect the DDP connection to figure out where the other users came from. It is unlikely that they originate from this publication. You should also provide a selector that is as granular as possible to the find() method.

Comment: When I checked the DDP connection, it appears that the subscription only returns 1 user which is expected. interestingly, when I log out my user, and sign in back again, it works fine now. I actually have another meteor app which is using the same database by MONGO_URL. I am not sure if that is related. just somehow the minimongo cached two users,  but now it works fine. this is strange

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to think about here.

1. When you request users you will always have "you". So if the user you are logged into is not an admin, it will still show up in the collection.
2. Because you are using `$meteor.subscribe` instead of `$scope.$meteorSubscribe` you are not clearing the subscription when the scope is destroyed so it's possible that it's  mixing with other subscriptions on the client side from other scopes.